# Is there a limit on editing?

Tags: discussion, support, edits

I was just wondering if there is a limit on editing. Like can you just edit anything you want and get reputation for it? Or is there a limit on how many things you can edit?

Comment: Your edits enter a review queue until you reach 2k rep (20k for tag edits), all of your edits will need to be approved by other users before being visible on site, and you'll only get reputation if your edit is actually approved

Comment: There is also a limit of 5 edits waiting to be approved. See [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide/164900#164900)

Comment: Keep in mind that when an edit is submitted for a post, that it is preferred to be a  [substantial edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/169692/158100) that fixes everything in the post. When reviewers of the edit encounter edits that do a partial fix they might reject the edit for being *too minor*. That can be an unsatisfactory outcome so better be aware of that upfront.

Comment: @rene "fix everything in the post": It is not likely for everyone to identify *every* mistake in a post. If the editor tried to fix *every* mistake *they could spot*, it is definitely an unsatisfactory outcome to have the edit rejected unless the reviewers give a satisfactory reason for rejection where *too minor* is an ambiguous rationale.

Comment: "Everything" to the best of your ability

Comment: There is no limit. Editing can go on and on, possibly forever.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As long as you don't have a reputation of 2,000 your edits have to be at least 6 characters long. These edits will be reviewed and if they are approved you get 2 points of reputation. Note however that edits can gain you only a maximum amount of 1,000 points, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) for details.

As soon as you reach 2,000 points, your edits will no longer undergo a review and can be less than 6 characters long. You will not get any reputation points for edits after you reached this limit.

Comment: There's also an FAQ on the uber meta - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work regarding suggested edits.